# How to detect opened windows in java

Tags: java

By using the below code I opened a window(say some software installer window) it went fine,
here I want to check weather the window got opened or not.

How to detect whether the window is *opened or not*?

Code snippet:-

```
  cmdarray = "......";
  Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
  Process responce = runTime.exec(cmdarray);
```

**What kind of Window**

**Ans**:- Installer anywhere window

At last I able to find the window is opened or not by using the solution provided by Hussain

If I want to close the window, how I can close it.....

I used **taskkill /F /IM << installer_window>>.exe** command in java(like runtime.exe("command");)to kill the process.
But window is not getting closed. Is there any way to close that window.

Thanks in Advance.

**@Hussain**

I tried as you said, but I am getting error like **ERROR: The process "proces.exe" with PID 4408 could not be terminated Reason: This process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option).** thats why I included **/F**, With the help of this I able to kill the process but window is not getting closed.

Please provide a quick solution, waiting for reply....

Thanks in Advance

Comment: how about check if a process is running or not ? this kind of checking is better to be written in Windows SDK ...

Comment: first try to kill some normal window like notepad or calculator or something

Comment: what is this process , give me a brief description , then i will try myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the complete list of all processes running in your windows, you can iterate it for your desired program to be running or not.

```
    public class taskmanager {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            String line;
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe");
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line); //<-- Parse data here.
            }
            input.close();
                String processToKill = "notepad++.exe"
                killProcess(processToKill);
        }
        public void killProcess(String processName)
        {
         Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /IM " + processName);
         }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Hussain, After finding the existance of window if I want to close it how to dot it. I tried **taskkill** command but its not working, for more details go through the (edited)description

Comment: I tried with notepad++.exe, I able to kill the process(window got closed). But in case of Installer Anywhere window I am getting this error **ERROR: The process "proces.exe" with PID 4408 could not be terminated Reason: This process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option).**, Even I tried with /F, with this I able to kill the process but not able to close the window.

Comment: first check whether proces.exe is missin a 's' or not

Comment: Hi Hussain, **Thanks for you support**At last I able to done it. **taskkill /T /F /IM \<<process>>.exe** command worked for me, in my case when I launch the installer, its creating a list of process that's why previous command not worked. Now As I included **/T** it kills all the list of process..

Comment: bravo , congrats , this is what we all want to help you initiate and finish by yourself